# Tesseract OCR iOS crashing for Arabic Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, tesseract

I've integrated tesseract OCR for 7-8 languages and all work fine. But when I try to integrate **Arabic**, it throws the following exception when "ara" is assigned as language:

```
G8RecognitionOperation *operation = [[G8RecognitionOperation alloc] init];
operation.tesseract.language = @"ara";
```

**tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 511**

Solutions i've tried (in vain):

1. I've tried adding the prefix: "lang." for arabic tessdata files
2. I've downloaded latest tessdata files from:
   https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
3. I've tried both tessdata versions i.e 3.01 and 3.02

So far nothing have worked, can someone please point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Arabic language normally work only in G8OCREngineModeCubeOnly but with this mode, I am getting same error.